# Algorythm to find factoradic for given number n which works in time O(log n)

Tags: c++, runtime, time-complexity, big-o

I have just written a code which does its job, but I have to optimize it to work in time `O(log n)`. The problem is that I'm not sure whether its time complexity is good and if it's not, how should I fix it?

Factoradic representation of a number is a sequence  s<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>k-1</sub> ... s<sub>2</sub>, s<sub>1</sub> that:

>   -> n = 1! * s
>   <sub>1</sub>
>   + 2! * s
>   <sub>2</sub>
>   + ... + k! * s
>   <sub>k</sub>
>   -> s
>   <sub>i</sub>
>   ≤ for i ∈ {1, 2, ..., k}
>   -> s
>   <sub>k</sub>
>   > 0
>   -> eg. 107 = 4! * 4 + 3! * 1 + 2! * 2 + 1! *1

My code:

```
unsigned long long int n;
unsigned long long int maxFact[21] = {0};

maxFact[0] = 1;
maxFact[1] = 1;

cout<<"Insert n: "; cin >> n;

int i = 2;
while (maxFact[i-1] * i <= n)  // find higher factorial <= n
{
    maxFact[i] = maxFact[i-1] * i;
    i++;
}

cout << "Factoradic representation of " << n << ":" << endl;

while (i > 1)
{
    cout << n / maxFact[i-1] << " ";
    n = n % maxFact[i-1];
    i--;
}
```

Comment: It might help if you define what a "factoradic" representation of a number is.

Comment: @hnefatl I don't know why, but it kept showing me that my definition of factoradic representation was a part of the code, but finally got it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example used in [this definition of factoradic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Definition) you can use `div()` to more rapidly determine the coefficients. You could implement that like

```
div_t result;
while (n != 0) {
  result = div(n, i);
  n = result.quot;
  maxFact[i++] = result.rem;
}
```

Where `div()` and `div_t` are included from `stdlib.h`.

This is fairly similar to what you have, except that `maxFact` is now storing the coefficients explicitly and only needs one loop for calculations. Your code looks like it is at least close to O(log n) but doing it as the above reduces the flops/n while still being algorithmically O(log n) - slightly more efficient, but not algorithmically superior. In fact the code in this answer runs on average 3x faster than the code in the question for `n` larger than 10- but we are splitting microseconds here (even up to the precision limit of `n`) so a factor of 3 is practically meaningless.

Comment: This helps a lot, but I would also like to know if there is any way to change my algorithm not to use any other libraries and work on basic operators (+ - * / %).

Comment: You can get the quotient and remainder separately using the `/` and `%` operators, there is no more primitive way to get both at once besides using `div()`. That would be fairly simple though - use the code in answer but replace `result = div(n, i)` with the lines `size_t quot = n / I` and `size_t rem = n % I` then use `quot` and `rem` instead of `result.quot` and `result.rem`. If this answer is sufficient then be sure to hit the check mark below the voting arrows to accept it - in case you didn’t already know.